# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowpenguin'

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-apps

```
(venv) E:\Studia Materialy\Semestr 4\IO\l02-nr-6-cyber-mechanik-l02team- master>python manage.py makemigrations L02
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\keray\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\keray\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\keray\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup    
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\keray\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\keray\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "E:\Programowanie\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowpenguin'
```

Can't run `python manage.py runserver` because of this problem, `python 3.7`, `Django 2.0.7`. I have tried many versions of python, and Django, I have also reinstalled bootstrap.

Comment: is `snowpenguin` in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS? apparently this app is not installed in your project

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to download `django-recaptcha` versions 2 & 3.  Might be different for you though.  Just follow @Lemayzeur's comment and look in your `INSTALLED_APPS` to find out what to download via `pip`.

Comment: django-recaptcha2==1.4.1 worked for me as of September 2020, thank you